# How to read a file from a different user's onedrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an excel file named "demo.xlsx" uploaded in the root folder of user A's onedrive. This file contains a table named "EmployeeTable". I want to login to my app as a different user - User 'B' and read data from this table.

I tried to login as user B and access the data using
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/8e92a7895e495d6623/drive/root:/demo.xlsx:/workbook/tables('EmployeeTable')/rows](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/8e92a7895e495d6623/drive/root:/demo.xlsx:/workbook/tables(%27EmployeeTable%27)/rows)

here **8e92a7895e495d6623** is user A's id. But I get the following error:

```
statusCode: 404, 
code: "itemNotFound",
body."message":"Item does not exist"
```

I have tried to share the file with user B by logging in to onedrive as user A and using the 'share' option, but I still get the above error.

When I login to my app as user A, and use the same URI as mentioned above, I am able to retrieve the data correctly.

Can anyone guide me on how to read an excel file from a different user's onedrive folder? I want to be able to keep this excel file in a common area like a user's onedrive folder and have multiple users read from it.

Note: the app that I have built is based on https://github.com/microsoftgraph/angular-excelstarter-sample

Answer (score 0):

If user A shares a file with user B and user B is currently logged in an app then call the endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe
```

The response will contain all files shared with user B. Find a file you need. The response should contain `remoteItem` node with `parentReference` child node.

```
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
"createdDateTime": "2021-01-05T09:51:23Z",
"id": "01BDYTYLL573DF4J3A2JG3WPFKMZLLBPQD",
...
"remoteItem": {
    "id": "01BDYTYLL573DF4J3A2JG3WPFKMZLLBPQD",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!RdjejBSERkqd6KyrlECzSlClLPMHvAxIle01z5BIuc0OlAR_j4bQQ5j8LT1dXapM",
        "driveType": "business",
        "id": "01BDYTYLN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
    },
....
```

Use the `driveId` and remote item's `id` and call this endpoint to access data

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{id}/workbook/tables('EmployeeTable')/rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to login to my app as user B and access the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe?allowexternal=true URI, but this returns an empty response although user A has shared a file with user B


`
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": []
}
`

I had to append allowexternal=true to the URI since both users are in different orgs. Any tips on how to resolve this?